# Can a workflow start a console app in SharePoint?

Tags: development, workflow, feature, app

I would just like to know, if it is possible to start a console app from a workflow in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't think this is a good idea. You are asking to start a exe from workflow. This is against security.

This questions has been asked earlier with a nice answer.

Have a look at it.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918052/sharepoint-workflow-and-starting-exe-file)

However you could start a [PowerShell Script](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Execute%20PowerShell%20Script%20Action) using workflow and in that PowerShell script you can [call your Console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-powershell-script).

Comment: Hi Varun, Thanks for the quick reply, and the good answer was clutching at straws. Will mark as answered as soon as i can. Thank again.